# Include outliers in ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

I conducted some interviews and I wanted to create box plots with ggplot based on these interviews. I managed to create the box plots but I do not manage to include the outliers in the box plot. I have only a few observations and therefore I want the outliers to be part of the box plot.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
data_insurances_boxplot_merged <- ggplot(data_insurances_merged, aes(x = value, y = func, fill = group)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 20, size = 3, color = "red",
               position = position_dodge2(width = 0.75,   
                                          preserve = "single")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 7, 1), limits = c(1, 7)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E6645E", "#EF9C9D")) +
  labs(x = "", 
       y = "", title = "") +
  theme_light(base_size = 12) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())

data_insurances_boxplot_merged
```

And this is the box plot that is generated:
[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Outlier should be shown with `geom_boxplot()`. You'd have to suppress them with `outlier.shape=NA`. Can you provide some dummy data? Alternatively, overlay all the points with `geom_point()`

Comment: What do you mean by "include the outliers in the box plot"? 

Do you mean (1) visualize them or (2) add them to the box? If (1), maybe change the `scale_x_continous()` and see first comment. if (2), by definition the outliers are not part of the boxlot (see https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-boxplots-5e2df7bcbd51). 


You might be more interested in a violin + boxplot combination to visualize the data: https://r-graph-gallery.com/violin_and_boxplot_ggplot2.html

Comment: You can set `coef = Inf` to take the data limits as the points to which the boxplots should extend the whiskers.